# Can Window OS handle multiple user same time as unix

Tags: windows

As we know UNIX is a computer Operating System which is capable of handling activities from multiple users at the same time. My question is that can **windows** have same capability? If 'yes' then 'how'?

Comment: "Start menu -> Switch user"

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I also know this is not a programming related question....but this is very interesting&useful question....for me.....and many one ask this type of question.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends upon your definition of "multiple users".

Processes can (and do) run under multiple user accounts all the time on all modern Windows systems (in this definition, I'm excluding the 95/98/ME line). This has been the case since at least NT 4.

Running multiple interactive user GUI sessions simultaneously, however, is restricted to specific editions of Windows (Server, Terminal Services, etc.). It's not so much a *technical* limitation as it is a *licensing* limitation. I'm unaware of limitations on the number of concurrent remote PSSessions supported by Windows (licensing- or technical-based).

Comment: I'd guess the use of pssessions would come under the "no more than ten incoming network connections" rule - unless that's been dropped in recent years?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Login using "user1". Run app with admin rights: it runs in "administrator" user group at a same time.